# How does the Eschweiler Clarke reaction occur with sodium cyanoborohydride as a reducing agent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity, organic-reduction

I am specifically confused with 2 concepts.

1. How sodium cyanoborohydride acts as a reducing agent. I read that it acts as a source of hydride but I am not sure how this works. If anything, I assumed that the hydrogens bound to the boron atom would have a delta positive charge.
2. In the first step, the primary amine performs a nucleophilic attack on the carbonyl carbon of formaldehyde, generating an intermediate with a positive nitrogen and a negative charge on the formaldehyde oxygen. How does the reduction to the iminium intermediate occur? I read that the hydride attacks the formaldehyde carbon but why is that the case? Should the positive nitrogen not be a more attractive target? Or the negative oxygen attack first?

Essentially, I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: It probably boils down to proximity and five/six-membered rings in transition states and reactive intermediates.

Comment: What conditions do you consider the Eschweiler–Clarke? Typically sodium cyanoborohydride is not present. Instead, formic acid acts as the reducing agent.